# Writing a variable number of database entries with Prisma

Tags: javascript, postgresql, prisma

I am working on an app that takes an individual and assigns them a set number of days per week for them to work, then it writes their schedule to a relational database using Prisma. In practice this looks like the following psudocode:

```
 const createTutor = await prisma.tutor.create({
        data: { 
            tutorName: tutorName,
            tutorPhone: +tutorPhone,
            tutorRate: +tutorRate,
            tutorEmail: tutorEmail
            availability: { **This is where I don't know what to do. Ideally I need to write a variable number of available day entries (that include a beginning time and an end time) to the database and connect both the tutor to their availability entries and the availability entries to the tutor.** }
```

Here is what my schema looks like for these two database entries:

```
model Tutor {
  tutorName         String               @unique
  tutorAvailability DailyAvailibility[]
  tutorRate         Int
  assignedStudents  TutoringAssignment[]
  linkedUser        User?
  completedSessions CompletedSession[]
  tutorPhone        BigInt
  tutorEmail        String
}

model DailyAvailibility {
  id                    Int    @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  tutor                 Tutor  @relation(fields: [tutorName], references: [tutorName])
  tutorName             String
  dayOfWeek             Int //0 being Sunday and 6 Saturday
  beginningAvailability Int
  endingAvailability     Int
}
```

I'd love to know how to do this correctly, I technically have it writing all the correct entries but it only links the tutorName to their dailyAvailibilty entries, it does not link the opposite. Here's the code I have now for my API that does this (if it helps understand what I am trying to do)

```
async function createAvailability(availability:any, tutorName:any) {
    
    for(let x=0; x<6; x++) {
        if(availability[x] != null) {
          let newAvailability = await prisma.dailyAvailibility.create({
            data: {
                dayOfWeek:x,
                beginningAvailability: +availability[x].beginningAvailability,
                endingAvailability: +availability[x].endingAvailability,
                tutor: {
                    connect: {
                        tutorName: tutorName
                    }
                }
            }
          })
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is write this all at once in such a way that the tutor entry is connected correctly to their dailyAvailabilities and the dailyAvailabilities all correctly are linked to their tutors. I should mention this is a postgresql database as well.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So, still reading about this problem. Is it possible I am misunderstanding the way relational databases work? Ideally I want to be able to query all the tutor table for availability data, but since it is one-to-many relation is the methodology to just query the availability data by tutor name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `create` field or `connectOrCreate` to create your availabilities right way, like that:

```
  const tutor = await prisma.tutor.create({
    data: {
      tutorName: 'tutorName',
      tutorPhone: 1,
      tutorRate: 1,
      tutorEmail: 'tutorEmail',
      tutorAvailability: {
        create: [
          { beginningAvailability: 1, endingAvailability: 1, dayOfWeek: 1 },
          { beginningAvailability: 2, endingAvailability: 2, dayOfWeek: 2 },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
```

And then to get either side of relation you just need to `include` it when you query for data:

```
  const availabilityWithTutor = await prisma.dailyAvailibility.findFirst({
    include: {
      tutor: true,
    },
  });

  // Tutor
  availabilityWithTutor?.tutor
  
  const tutorWithAvailability = await prisma.tutor.findFirst({
    include: {
      tutorAvailability: true,
    },
  });
 
  // Array<DailyAvailibility>
  tutorWithAvailability?.tutorAvailability
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the nested create inside of the tutor create with a variable number of potential availability entries? I'm populating the availability array only with days that tutors are available so it could have three days or two or only one. The other option is to make a static sized array with 5 elements that has a property specifying if a tutor is available on a given day, but that seems inelegant if we can do the write with a variable number of potential daysAvailable. Also, thanks for the reply. I greatly appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Nested create for what exactly? Not quite following. You just passing an array to create, it can have any amount of entries basically, 1, 2, 5, 100.

Comment: I guess I am misunderstanding the syntax :  

`tutorAvailability: {
        create: [
          { beginningAvailability: 1, endingAvailability: 1, dayOfWeek: 1 },
          { beginningAvailability: 2, endingAvailability: 2, dayOfWeek: 2 },
        ],`

This looks like it calls create for a static array with a length of two, I don't know how large my array will be (it will vary based on availability) so does this or other syntax cover an unknown array length? Apologies for being dense - your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I mean, it's just regular JS syntax here, you are passing arguments to a function, so of course you can pass any array there, construct it in runtime and etc.